# Please explain this code , a beginner in python here

Tags: python, python-2.7

I solved this question with long for loops and adding elements in set.As a beginner its quite complicated for me to comprehend what basically is written in this snippet.Also please explain what key does basically.In this we have to print the sorted output of the symmetric difference of two sets.

I/P :

```
4 (Integer representing Length of first set )
2 4 5 9 (First set )
4 (Integer representing Length of second set )
2 4 11 12 (Second set )
```

O/P

```
5
9
11
12
```

The solution:

```
a,b = [set(raw_input().split()) for _ in range(4)][1::2]
print '\n'.join(sorted(a^b, key=int))
```

Comment: Question is very unclear. Please provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[set(raw_input().split()) for _ in range(4)]
```

turns each line of input into a *set of strings*.  `[1::2]` selects the sets created from lines 2 and 4.  The `key=int` option says to sort the strings within the symmetric different by their integer value.  Otherwise, '11' would sort before '2'.

EDIT: In general, the `key` options says to temporarily replace each item in the iterable to be sorted with a tuple `(key(item), item)` (in a new list), sort the list of tuples, and then replace each now-sorted tuple with the item.  This is call 'decorate, sort, undecorate'.

Comment: But when I used sorted in python shell it produced the sorted output.I don't understand the use of key here , is it very important to use key here?

Comment: `sorted(('5', '9', '11', '12'))` is `['11', '12', '5', '9']`, which is not the order you requested.

Comment: Ohh ! Thanks alot I get it now.